# Get an array of IDs(values) from a datatable

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, collections, datatable

I have a datable with 50 rows and has an ID Column. I am trying to get an array that holds only the IDs like:

```
string [] IDs = (from row in DataTable.Rows
                select row["ID"].toString()).ToArray();
```

Is there a way to do this. I always get the error "Could not find he implementation of the query...."

Comment: Why stop there you tease... tell us the WHOLE error message.

Comment: That lowercase `toString()` is just a typo, isn't it?

Comment: @Man, yes typo. Wrote the code by hand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) by adding a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` and a `using System.Data;` Then you should be able to use the following query:

```
var query = from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
            select row["ID"].ToString();
string[] ids = query.ToArray();
```

If you really need an array you can use the last line above or enclose the query in parentheses and call `ToArray()` as you did originally. I'm generally not a fan of the latter approach.

In fluent syntax it would be:

```
string[] ids = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(row => row["ID"].ToString())
                        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I tried that I get: 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable'. Is there something I need to reference

Comment: @Robert add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` and add the `System.Data` namespace via: `using System.Data;` since the `AsEnumerable` method for the DataTable is different than the usual one.

Answer (score 0):

is there is anyway you can select a list data table into a customer object array. Assuming all the columns are going to be same.